# Return entity data as per string character matching

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return a string matching search result. In example bellow you can see i did a funny practice. The Description is large text collection like- "The cow is a domestic animal" even more large text description. Now my question is when i input some part of string like "cow" then entity framework should return me all "cow" related items data. How to do this?

Controller code:

```
using (var db = new TestEntities())
            {
                var returnedSearchData =  db.Products.Where(x => x.Description == SrcKey).ToList();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you.. ?

**LINQ**

```
var matches = from m in db.Products
where m.Name.Contains("cow")      
select m;
```

**Entity Framework**

```
using (var db = new TestEntities())
        {
            var returnedSearchData =  db.Products.Where(x => x.Description.Contains("cow")).ToList();
        }
```